# How to make this remove role command work properely?

Tags: discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def number_4(ctx, role):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = role)
    await ctx.author.remove_roles(role)
```

I'm not really sure how to make this work properly...

Comment: Which part is failing?  Are you unable to get the role object, or is removing it failing?  What error message are you getting?  Does you bot have the manage roles permission?  Are you trying to manage a role that is higher in the role hierarchy than your bots highest role?

Comment: Nothing is failing, and no error. However, it doesn't remove roles. I tried a higher role, and a lower role. Both doesn't work

Comment: Could you try adding some prints to see if the command is being called at all?  Do you have an `on_message` event?

Answer (score 1):

I've made a few changes. When calling the command you want to mention the role: @role

Keep in mind this will only work if the bot has a role higher up than the role you are trying to remove.

```
@client.command()
async def number_4(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    await ctx.message.author.remove_roles(role)
```